# changing button text on click, problem with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think the code explains what I'm trying to do. The problem is the delay doesn't work.

```
 $( "#AddToCart" ).click(function() {
       $("#AddToCartText").text("Adding");
       $("#AddToCartText").delay(500).text("Add to cart");
  });
```

Comment: use `setTimeout` for delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued **jQuery effects**. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—`.delay()` is not a replacement for JavaScript's native `setTimeout` function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

```js
$( "#AddToCart" ).click(function() {
       $("#AddToCartText").text("Adding")
       setTimeout(function() { 
          $("#AddToCartText").text("Add to cart");; 
       }, 500);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button>
<div id="AddToCartText">
```

Answer (score 1):

`delay()` defaults to the animation queue, for effects like fadeOut(), etc. Use `setTiemout` instead of `delay`. Try below code-

```js
$("#AddToCart").click(function() {
  $("#AddToCartText").text("Adding");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#AddToCartText").delay(500).text("Add to cart")
  }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="AddToCartText"></div>
<Button id="AddToCart">Click It!</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `delay` in these way, or you can use `setTimeout`

```js
$( "#AddToCart" ).click(function() {
       $("#AddToCartText").text("Adding");
      // $("#AddToCartText").delay(1000).text("Add to cart");
       $('#AddToCartText').delay(600).queue(function(n) { 
        $(this).text("Add to cart"); n();
      })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="AddToCart"> Add </button>

<span id="AddToCartText"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The delay method is only for queued items (mostly animation) in jQuery. If you want to do a change like this you must use `setTimeout`.

```js
$("#AddToCart").click(function() {
  $("#AddToCartText").text("Adding");
  setTimeout("setback()", 500);
});

function setback() {
  $("#AddToCartText").text("Add to cart");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="AddToCart">Add To Cart</button>
<div id="AddToCartText"></div>
```